# Auto Text Recognition (OCR) from Image

Tags: image-processing, ocr, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I want to recognize nutrient information from package labels [Sample Nutrient label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prk03.jpg) . This is one package image, different brands may style/layout their labels differently. But I know some things for sure, layout would be somewhat tabular with certain key words in heading like 'Nutrient' as well as the content of the table will have certain common words, like Energy/Fat etc. I want to extract these values in text form and save it into my db.

The sample image is part of a bigger problem, finding the contour/box that might contain this section 'Nutrient Label'.

As I understand their are 3 broad steps.

1. Scan the input image (product front/back/side image) to look for the best contour that could be my target contour containing these nutrient information
2. Go to this contour and perform OCR (possibly retain the layout information and not output everything in 1 line)
3. scan the text and look for needed info.

I am a beginner in Image Recognition. it would be a great help,

1. If i could get a feedback on my approach. for instance should I look for text in Image or gather similar images and train a model and then do classification? similar to performing face recognition.
2. if someone has already solved this problem, it would be great to get some pointers (their is no fun reinventing the wheel).
3. If its a research problem, then relevant code/libraries/pointers/similar SO questions that I could refer to.

It would be highly appreciable if the answers are not general (like perform feature extraction, I would no clue what is feature extraction, instead a sample code pointer would be awesome.)

I thank you for your time and help.

thanks
Chahat

Answer (score 0):

1. It would be required to collect at least 200-300 images for sufficient training.

2/3. I did solve the problem, but it was done using not a free solution, so I'm not supposed to give a directions here.